# generate sample example in swagger UI (in Spring boot project)

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using a spring boot application and have configured using Swagger UI.

I want to know whether we could pre-populate the example value with sample value so we can hit the "Try it out!" button without having to type in some sample values to get a response.

It must be present there.

Is there a way we can do this using annotations or a separate file which Swagger uses?

I am using a spring boot project with springfox-swagger2:2.7.0 and springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0 with dependencies added using gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `@ApiParam` properties `example` and `examples` are not working (see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/853)), support for adding examples is limited/non existing.

What you can do for simple parameters (`@RequestParam`) is to add the `@ApiParam` annotation with the `defaultValue` property, like this:

```
@GetMapping
public List<Foo> findAll(
        @RequestParam(required = false)
        @ApiParam(defaultValue = "foo") // Put the default value here
        String input) {
    // ...
}
```

However, there is no support yet for doing this with `@RequestBody` parameters.

A possible workaround for `@RequestBody` parameters is by clicking on the code box at the right side of the Swagger tester, where it says **Example value**. If you click on it, it will insert that example into the field itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Meanwhile I just read about swashbuckle here https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/ but its seems its for .NET only. Anything available for Java Spring.

Comment: Pretty sure Springfox is the best approach to generate Swagger docs for Spring.

Comment: It's pretty easy to wire it up to use examples via plugins. But for your need @g00glen00b's suggestion would work great!!

Comment: i want to do the same with Example Value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for providing an example:

Inject html into swagger

```
@ApiParam(
    name="whatever",
    value="whatever",
    defaultValue="none</p><p>Example: xyz</p>"
)
```

They don't protect against it in the latest version `2.9.2`.